# Change the battery percentage warning on MacBooks?

Tags: macos, macbook, battery

Is it possible to modify when the "Low Battery" sign appears on a MacBook with Snow Leopard? For example, currently, it warns you about a low battery when it hits 10% of the overall battery charge. What if I want to set it to alert me on 15% or on 20%? How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of changing the internal notifications. The only thing you can do is create your own new ones.

```
set a to do shell script "pmset -g batt | grep %"

set text item delimiters to tab
set a to text item 2 of a
set text item delimiters to "%"
set a to text item 1 of a as integer

if a < 20 then display dialog "Battery at 20%"
```

This code when run will check the current charge of the battery and prompt you if it's under 20%. You would have to run this script at small intervals for it to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Although I'm quite positive that I managed to change it before. Or maybe that was on the Windows side of the macbook.